# Which 'info' and 'salt' parameters to use in HKDF for TLS 1.3?

Tags: diffie-hellman, tls, key-derivation, pseudo-random-generator, hkdf

all the following discussion is for HKDF in TLS1.3:

- Regarding the 'salt' parameter in - *HKDF-Extract(**salt**, IKM)*

  as written in [RFC 5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869):

  > HKDF without having to protect the secrecy of the salt.  In a    different application domain, a key agreement protocol deriving
  > cryptographic keys from a Diffie-Hellman exchange can **derive a salt
  > value from public nonces exchanged** and authenticated between
  > communicating parties as part of the key agreement (this is the
  > approach taken in [IKEv2]).

  From what it seems, the client's random nonce is used for the salt,
  but I cannot find any documentation about it in the TLS 1.3 RFC, am I
  correct?

---

- And regarding the 'info' paramter in *HKDF-Expand(PRK, **info**, L)*:

  Is it identical to the 'label' which's used in TLS 1.2 for PRF? Or
  are there new values for TLS 1.3 when deriving keys?

  I'm just really confused about which parameter should be passed in
  each stage.

  For example, when deriving the master-secret with the relevant hash,
  shared-secret, which 'info' parameter should be passed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you quote the specific parts of https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-7.1 that you're unsure about?

Comment: I wasn't sure why the function is in a different format than the Expand/Extract, is that supposed to be the wrapper for them?

Comment: The TLS key schedule is all defined in terms of HKDF-Extract and HKDF-Expand.   See the diagram on page 93, with a description of how to interpret it on page 92.

Comment: Oh! So in that diagram the "derived" input is the 'info' parameter when computing the master-secret?

Comment: The master secret is given by HKDF-Extract(salt=Derive-Secret(handshake secret, "derived", ""), ikm=(empty string)), which is, incidentally, the HMAC under key Derive-Secret(handshake secret, "derived", "") of the empty string.

Comment: Sorry for continuing with silly questions, but I still cannot understand the difference there.. :/

Comment: Why don't you start by going through the diagram vertex by vertex and writing down an expression for computing each named part?  For example, write down an expression in terms of HKDF-Extract for what you think the early secret is; then write down an expression for what you think the binder key is, and then the handshake secret, and so on.

Comment: I think I got it, basically the flow is expressing different parts during the handshake, where as if I wanted to compute the key after resumption, I'd have needed the output of the Extract with the relevant key, and use it with the info "res master" in order to compute it with Expand?

Comment: Almost: the string `res master` _figures into_ the info, whose full encoding (which includes a transcript of all past messages!) is shown on page 91 in the definitions of Derive-Secret and HKDF-Expand-Label.

Comment: Great, I'll continue investigating it, but it's a lot clearer now. Thanks!